# Test if Login Failed in PHP

Tags: php

If user login attempt fails, I wanna write something under the login form like I do in Asp.NET `(lblResult.Text = "Login Failed")`

Here is the Login for example:

```
<body>
        <form  method="post">
            Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
            Password: <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
            <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
```

And if login fails, right under the form, "Login failed" kind of message should be shown but I don't know any other way besides adding the whole form code with echo or something.

Thanks.

Comment: The question title does not describe what you are trying to do. What is "this"? Please fix it.

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can mix PHP in with your HTML.  `<p>Some text <?php echo "MORE TEXT"; ?> yet more text.</p>`

Comment: You could use AJAX, that would be more ASP-like.

Comment: Hey Tomalak,I couldn't find a proper and descriptive title for my question. If you know any, please go ahead and fix it.

Comment: I wrote a bit more descriptive title, not that yours was "completely" shot, but you explained yourself in the body, which to me is more important than getting the title to be 100% accurate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add something like this where you want the message:

```
<?php if ($loginFailed): ?>
  <div class="errorMessage">Login Failed</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Note, I'm using the [alternative control structure syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), which is slightly nicer than curly braces when writing spaghetti.

Comment: Just curious; what's 'writing spaghetti'? First time I ever heard that.

Comment: Maybe what I meant was "when trying to keep your intermingled PHP and HTML from becoming spaghetti."

Answer (score 3):

Are you posting it to another file? You could simply assign a response and echo it after the form:

`//do logic php logic here, if correct redirect if not assign $response here`

```
<body>
    <form  method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <?php echo $response; ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using ajax and simply posting to the same page, you can do something like:

```
<form>...</form>
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['username'])
  {
    // non-successful login
  }
?>
```

I am assuming you are setting your successful login in a session variable.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just put the "login failed" in a variable when the form fails to submit and then do the following in your code?

```
<body>
    <form  method="post">
        Username: <input type="text" name="username"/><br />
        Password: <input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
    <? if(isset($failed) { echo "<div>" . $failed . "</div>"; } ?>
</body>
```